# Как установить gyazo на дебиан

Tags: debian, установка

Столкнулся с проблемой установки gyazo на дебиан.

Инструкции с [github](https://github.com/gyazo/Gyazo-for-Linux) было не достаточно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Устанавливается следующим образом:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gdebi

$ wget https://github.com/downloads/kambara/Gyazo-for-Linux/gyazo_1.0-1_all.deb

$ sudo gdebi gyazo_1.0-1_all.deb
```

Программа появляется в списке стандартных приложений.

Comment: а `dpkg -i` не работало?